# store JSON data for later calls in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that works on a piece of JSON data object.
This data needs to be calculated by the plugin only once, so I want to calculate it on the first call to the plugin and store it to be used in every subsequent call.
My questtion is whether there's a standard and accepted methodology for storing data used by jQuery plugins.
Assuming my plugin is:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function(){...}
```

I was thinking of storing it's calculated data in:

```
jQuery.myPlugin.data = {...}
```

Is this the acceptable way of going about it?

Comment: Why don't you store it in `jQuery.fn.myPlugin.__data`? Or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think storing it there is acceptable (or `jQuery.fn.myPlugin.data` for that matter)...or instead use your own ID in `$.cache` which is for storage but uses integer IDs for jQuery events and data, so you won't have any conflict, for example:

```
$.cache["myPlugin"] = myData;
//and to get:
var dataToUse = $.cache["myPlugin"];
```

The main reason I'd take this route is it eliminates the *potential* `jQuery.something` naming conflicts that could arise with future versions.